# Githooks run inside docker with `git add` leads to `index.lock` troubles

Tags: git, githooks

I am running a Git hooks (with [Githooks](https://github.com/gabyx/Githooks)) where I run my `pre-commit` hook over a docker container:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run -rm -v "$(pwd):/workspace" -w "/workspace" myimage:1.0.0 bash script.sh
```

the `script.sh` basically does some `git add .` at the end.

When running `git commit ...` this leads to an error saying `.git/index.lock` cannot be created. My hook can run `git add .` when not dispatched over a docker container successfully.

Is there a way to allow the `git` process inside the docker container to also successfully execute `git add .` I mean I cannot simply delete the `.git/index.lock` that would be stupid.

Comment: "My hook can run git add . when not [in docker]" : do you mean that running `./script.sh` from your shell works ? or that calling `script.sh` (without using docker) *from your `pre-commit` hook* works when you execute `git commit` ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permission problem.

Since you're not mounting read-only, I'm assuming the problems is that "myimage:1.0.0" defaults to a user (within the container) that has a different UID than your workspace folder's owner.

If you can't adjust the container user's UID in the image (in `/etc/passwd`) to match your local user, you could try to temporarily adjust the permissions of the entire `.git` directory so that the container user can create/modify files in there.

Comment: one way to check the default user that runs within your container : `docker run --rm myimage:1.0.0 bash -c 'echo $USER; echo -n "UID="; id -u $USER; echo -n "GID="; id -g $USER'`